# Firebase GET request not returning data to client

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

We have an app with a firestore database, using firebase cloud functions. We are trying to get data about each user from an external API. Our firebase cloud function is returning data - I can see it correctly in the logs. However, I cannot see that data in the browser. I'm guessing maybe I'm not using async/await properly?

Here's how we're calling the function from our app (in Vuex):

```
async retrieveByExternalId({ commit }, payload) {
      const retrieveByExternalId = await firebase.functions().httpsCallable('retrieveByExternalId')
      retrieveByExternalId({
        id: payload
      })
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result.data)
        commit('setUserContractorPayProfile', result.data)
      })
    },
```

Result.data shows as null

Then, here's the cloud function:

```
exports.retrieveByExternalId = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const id = data.id
  
  axios({
    method: "GET",
    url: `https://website/api/v2/workers/external/${id}`,
    headers: {
      accept: '*', 
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      Authorization: 'API KEY'
    }
  })
  .then(response => {
    functions.logger.log("Response", " => ", response.data);
    return response.data
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    functions.logger.log("Error", " => ", error);
  })
});
```

In the functions log, I can see everything correctly.

Is it an async/await issue? Or am I returning data wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried your code but the problem is most probably due to the fact you don't return the [promise chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#chaining) in your Cloud Function.

You should either do:

```
  return axios({  // <====== See return here
    // ...
  })
  .then(response => {
    functions.logger.log("Response", " => ", response.data);
    return response.data
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    functions.logger.log("Error", " => ", error);
  })
```

or, since you declared the function `async`, use the `await` keyword as follows:

```
exports.retrieveByExternalId = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    try {
        const id = data.id

        const axiosResponse = await axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: `https://website/api/v2/workers/external/${id}`,
            headers: {
                accept: '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                Authorization: 'API KEY'
            }
        });

        functions.logger.log("Response", " => ", axiosResponse.data);
        return axiosResponse.data
    } catch (error) {
        // see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors
    }
    
});
```